# Batch code for execution of .exe files with parameters

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

My Command line arguments for my question is

getpkt.exe  15-05-14.dlf

The getpkt.exe file and .dlf file are in the same folder. Now i will copy the batch file to the same location and just double click that. so it need to execute the command.

The folder contains only one getpkt.exe and one .dlf file. But .dlf file name varies every time.

So anyone help me with the batch script code where it need to execute the following getpkt.exe file with the.dlf file in the same folder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `@pushd "%~f0"&for %%F in (*.dlf) do @getpkt "%%F"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. goto the correct path
2. get the filename (if there are more than one, this will get the last one)
3. execute the program with the filename as parameter

   cd /d "C:\path to getpkt"

   for /f %%i in ('dir /b *.dlf') do set file=%%i

   getpkt.exe %file%

Comment: HI Even it need to get path every time and should work from there. Path is also changeable..

Comment: You don't know the path? uhh  you can search for `*.dlf` or `getpkt.exe` in the whole drive and get it's path - but that will need a good amount of time... Do you at least have some hints, where to start the search?

Comment: My requirement is, i will just copy the three files(Getpkt, .dlf &.bat) in the required folder and will double click the .bat file. then it need to search the .dlf file in the same folder and should give an argument in the command prompt.

Comment: Hello Stephen,Here is the code i have developed. and observed that it is working fineSET mypath=%~dp0
echo %mypath:~0,-1%\
cd /d "%~dp0"
for /f %%i in ('dir /b *.dlf') do set file=%%i
getpkt.exe %file%
Exit

Answer (score 0):

SET mypath=%~dp0
echo %mypath:~0,-1%\
pushd "%~dp0"
for /f %%i in ('dir /b *.dlf') do set file=%%i
getpkt.exe %file%
Exit